# What are the travel restrictions if I take a flight from USA to India which stops in London or Dubai?

Tags: international-travel, covid-19

I am travelling to India for my vacation. I am planning to book a flight from USA to India roundtrip. I currently live in North Carolina, USA and trying to fly through Air India as it has direct flights to India from USA. But in my case the departure airport for Air India are very far and I am looking for other options like British airways or Emirates. So if I choose to fly through either British or Emirates, they have a stop at London or Dubai. But When I was going through this link: https://boi.gov.in/sites/default/files/u4/Guidelinesforinternationalarrivals17022021.pdf

I have found a section which says : "*For all international travellers coming/transiting through flights originating from UnitedKingdom, Europe and Middle East*" and has more restrictions that people travelling from other countries.

So does this section applies to me? if fly through British airways from USA to India?

Comment: Stating the obvious: travel for vacation at the moment is not a great idea. Lots of rules and restrictions are in place and they change quickly with little or no advanced notice and most websites etc are stale and not up to date. The rules may  say today "you can travel this itinerary", but that there is no guarantee that they are the same on departure day, While the Corona situation is improving in most places, it is still very unpredictable and in some places are getting worse again. For example Italy went into lockdown again last week.   It would be best to wait a few months.

Answer (score 5):

If your itinerary transits through the UK, or through the Middle East, or both, the cited document indicates the greater restrictions apply to you.

The identity of the air carrier(s) has no relevance.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking particularly for restrictions in India - any restrictions in place applicable to people arriving from UK would be applicable to you even if UK is a transit stop in your case.
What you might additionally want to consider are how the state restrictions differ in India. For example for people arriving from UK I believe Delhi currently has no mandatory institutional quarantine if provided with a negative Covid test result whereas Mumbai mandates hotel quarantine.